# Restore clion default settings on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, clion

i've managed to screw up my clion settings and its practically useless now. reinstall doesn't help cause there are remaining config files.

ive followed the ubuntu related instruction here: 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcPlq.jpg)
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html
i ran the commands in terminal but the directory wasn't found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remove .idea in project directory?

Comment: What commands did you run? On that page are not commands but a tip of where to find the config folder. Could you please try running `ls ~/.CLion*` for finding it? Im assuming you are using Linux based on the image you shared.